# How to add a deppendecy to a build.gradle?

Tags: android, mobile, gradle, android-support-library

I'm wanting use this github project: https://github.com/makovkastar/FloatingActionButton in my android app, however I dont know if I have to download the project and move to libraries package, or if I have only do this:

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.1.0'
}
```

Comment: According to [the installation instructions](https://github.com/makovkastar/FloatingActionButton#integration), you only need to add that dependency.

Comment: But where I put the github project? In the libraries package? That is the first time I'm using gralde!

Comment: "But where I put the github project? " -- the only reason why you would need the project is if you are planning on modifying the library. If you are just using the library, you do not need the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need search the file `build.gradle` of your whole app folder.

There should be 2 of them, open the file under `app` folder you will see some like:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.2'
    compile 'com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.1.0'
}
```

Put `compile 'com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.1.0'` in dependencies

Comment: Thanks, now is more undestanding for me :D

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to download the source code if just want to use the library.
Just add line compile `'com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.1.0'` to `dependencies` section in  `build.gradle`

Comment: I'm very grateful, it was not explicit at the blogs that I did read.